# How to maintain this custom ListView with dynamic layout?

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, view

**Here is the Wireframe:**

```
Custom ListView

- View
    {
        it contains,

        ImageView, TextView, TextView, LinearLayout
    }

    - LinerLayout
        {
            it contains,

            dynamically add Views in this layout.
        }
```

**So, ListView pattern is not same (i.e. View row is not same.)**

In this case, how to maintain **convertView**?

because Listview row must have **same view inside**. **isn't it ?**

Please suggest me any way to get out of this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary that all views of the listview have to be the same.

If you check out the typical getView() method of a list adapter, it's something like this :

```
View v = convertView;   
if (v == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi;
    vi = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_1, null);    
}
```

You can very much use this to have views of different layouts :

```
View v = convertView;   
if (v == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi;
    vi = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    if(itemList.get(position).getType() == 1) {
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_1, null);    
    } else {
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_2, null);    
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to maintain somewhere the items that you want to place in this listView as an ArrayList for example. With each object of the arraylist, you can store the type of the layout that you want to use. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is method in your adapter see **getItemViewcount()** that should return 2
and **getItemViewType()**
in getItemview according to your condition

1.in **getView()**
call **getItemViewType()** that will return **0** in case first and **1** in case second according to that return view

```
int retrunCondton =getItemViewType();
switch(retrunCondton){
case 0:
View
    {
        it contains,

        ImageView, TextView, TextView, LinearLayout
    }
break;
case 1:
LinerLayout
        {
            it contains,

            dynamically add Views in this layout.
        }
break;
}
```

return view;